# What's the cause of one second freezes on iOS 13 when ARKit calls nextDrawable?

Tags: xcode, augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit, ios13

I'm trying to debug a problem with 1-second freezes in ARKit on iOS 13 when `SCNRenderer` calls `[CAMetalLayer nextDrawable]` (which [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cametallayer/1478172-nextdrawable?language=objc) does say can freeze for that duration). It's not hard to reproduce the problem but it does only happen randomly about half the time the app is run.

When the problem is occurring there are two rendering queues visible, one marked `ARSCNView` and the other `SCNView`, as shown in this screenshot:

[image: queue screenshot]

I think the two queues are always there, it's just I only see them when breaking into the debugger when stuck on the `nextDrawable` call.

Only saw this problem when iOS 13.1 came along but it's possible I just missed it on iOS 13. Posting this question hoping someone else is working on the same thing right now...

Answer (score 0):

#### It's a notorious bug

This often occurs when we run Metal-based AR apps in Xcode's Debug mode on iPhone Simulator.

#### Solution

After an app's built in Xcode's Debug mode, just disconnect a device from computer, quit an app and launch app disconnected from computer. AR app will launch without any freeze at all.

Comment: Same issue exists with ios 14.2 and Xcode 12.2